# Return Statistics Post Page Facebook

Tags: facebook

Using api v2.9.

```
include('controller/facebook/init.php');


 try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get(
    '/POST_ID/likes',
    'ACCESS_TOKEN',
    'summary=total_count'
  );
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$graphEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
print_r($graphEdge);
```

The goal in question is to get the total likes of the post, I also believe that changing the term 'likes' for shares or comments will return the data corresponding to the post.

The print returned is that of the image, but the total is not returned.

[image]

Comment: Third parameter for the `get` method in the v5 PHP SDK is `$etag`, according to documentation - so what you are passing here makes no sense. Try and append the parameter directly to the endpoint address.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me this way

```
$response = $fb->get(
    '/POST_ID/likes?summary=true',
    'ACCESS_TOKEN'
  );
```